# iOS - UIWebView loading an image located in the tmp folder

Tags: ios, image, uiwebview

I have an image file saved in the application's temp folder, say IMG.png. I am injecting an HTML string into a UIWebView using:

```
    NSString *HTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"<body><h2>%@</h2><img src=\"%@\"></img><p>%@</p>%@</body>",
                     title, image, body];

    [webView loadHTMLString:HTML baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:HOST]];
```

I tried many combinations of paths for the NSString `image`, but I cannot get this WebView to load my local image properly.

Can you please help me?

Here's what I use to save my image in the temp folder:

```
[self saveImage:result withFileName:post.title ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:NSTemporaryDirectory()];
```

which relies on:

```
-(void) saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {

    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Image Save Failed\nExtension: (%@) is not recognized, use (PNG/JPG)", extension);
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple things: instead of doing "`error: nil`" in your calls to "`writeToFile`", you should check to see if that function returns "`TRUE`" and that if not, print out the value returned in the error parameter.  Secondly, you should show examples of what your "`image`" path being passed into that HTML string looks like.

Comment: The file is being written properly, I've checked in the simulator folder, so I don't see any point on looking at the error. secondly, the "image" value is what I'm asking for!

Comment: is the file always the same name or can it be different names?  Is the object which is composing the HTML string the same object that is saving the image to a file?  The reason I ask is because we can then make the image path or the file name an object ivar.

Comment: The file name can be different. On the other hand the object composing the HTML is the same as the one saving the image

Answer (score 0):

```
     [webView loadHTMLString:HTML baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:HOST]]; //the 'HOST' must be your application's temp folder
```

Answer (score 0):

try composing the file URL with NSURL:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"jpg"]];
NSString *image = [url absoluteString];
```

(Assume your image filename is "filename.jpg")

should result in something like:

```
file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/E754629C-4163-4829-9D10-89D55A61264E/tmp/filename.jpg
```

Hope this helps.